# Rails nested objects disappearing when validation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I took a look at some sollutions but none of them worked for me. I have a form that creates a fixed number of nested objects (5 times). It works fine, but the problem is when there's a validation error: the form is displayed without the 5 nested objects. I could rebuild the objects on controller, but that would make their value blank, replacing the user input, so it's not desirable.

My model:

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :question_status
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :choices

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :choices, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes[:content].blank? }, limit: 5

  validates :content, :source, presence: true
  validate :check_number_of_choices,


  def check_number_of_choices
    if self.choices.select{|c| c.content.present?}.size != 5
        self.errors.add :choices, I18n.t("errors.messages.number_of_choices")
    end
  end

end
```

My view:

```
<%= form_with(model: question, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if question.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(question.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this question from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% question.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :content %>
    <%= form.text_area :content %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :source %>
    <%= form.text_field :source %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :year %>
    <%= form.number_field :year %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :choices %>

    <%= form.fields_for :choices do |choice| %>
      <p>
          - <%= choice.text_field :content %>
      </p>
    <% end %>

  </div>


  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My controller:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_question, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /questions
  # GET /questions.json
  def index
    @questions = Question.all
  end

  # GET /questions/1
  # GET /questions/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /questions/new
  def new
    @question = Question.new
    5.times { @question.choices.build }
  end

  # GET /questions/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /questions
  # POST /questions.json
  def create
    @question = Question.new(question_params)
    @question.question_status = QuestionStatus.find_or_create_by(name: "Pending")
    @question.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @question.save
        format.html { redirect_to @question, notice: 'Question was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @question }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /questions/1
  # PATCH/PUT /questions/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @question.update(question_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @question, notice: 'Question was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @question }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /questions/1
  # DELETE /questions/1.json
  def destroy
    @question.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to questions_url, notice: 'Question was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_question
      @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def question_params
      params.require(:question).permit(:content, :source, :year, :question_status_id, :user_id, choices_attributes: [:id, :content])
    end
end
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got my answer:
the problem was on :reject_if on my model. When I take it off, it works fine. Don't know exactly why and still don't got a fix for it

Comment: Not really a great answer but: Does it work if you add `5.times { @question.choices.build }` to your else statement in the create action, above `format.html { render :new }` ?